# Getting 401 Unauthorized on Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-automation

I am trying to get the BitLocker rotation key to work with Azure Automation but I am stuck on the permission needed for it.

I am following this article [True BitLocker one-time key with Intune](https://msendpointmgr.com/2020/10/05/true-bitlocker-one-time-recovery-key-with-intune/), everything works fine with the alert being fired wherever a user check the BitLocker Key on myaccount.microsoft.com, but the key is not getting rotated due to the error 401 Unauthorized, as far I understand 401 means you were able to access the service but does not have permission to perform the action which on this case is the BitLocker rotation.

Here is what I tried to so far.

Verified the necessary permission for Microsoft Graph which is DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWrite.All, correctly assigned
Added Global Admin role
Added a license to enterprise application

But still no luck. As mentioned wherever I verify the BitLocker key under myaccounts the alert fire the runbook on the time I set it to run, but no rotation due to the error 401.

Furthermore, I also tried to manually run the command in graph using one of my GA accounts [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWZr4.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHCLv.jpg)and it worked.

Also one more point on the article mentioned above the script is using run as an account, but since it is no longer available I am using system managed identity.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the permission I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it sorted by making a different graph call, now wherever the alert is fired the key rotation is being called successfully.

Thanks everyone